# How do I get this Loop to start with a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle
import random
#these imports are for the other parts of the code, I only pasted the parts that keep the code below working

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print("bot is ready. ")

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def Test_lol():
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNELID)
    await channel.send("Test")
    #test two
@client.command()
async def timer_start(ctx):
    await ctx.Test_lol.start

client.run('MY TOKEN')
```

I know the `ctx.Test_lol.start` is the issue but I'm not really sure how to get the loop started with a command so I experimented with `ctx`. If anyone could provide some insight on how to manually start the loop It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why `ctx.Test_lol.start()`? Where did you take that from? Why not simply `Test_lol.start()`?

Comment: I pretty much got confused on how to use ctx, well I know that something like 
 async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! ) would function with .ping and return the string there and I thought I could try to execute a loop in that way using the command like that, Thanks for the clarification tho

Comment: Also - when awaiting `Task.start` you're waiting for it to finish, if you want to just start it and run it in the background you shouldn't await it, i.e `Test_lol.start()` instead of `await Test_lol.start()`

Comment: ctx doesnt have an attribute called `Test_lol`. remove the ctx and it'll work

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def timer_start(ctx):
    Test_lol.start()
```